# ember how to add multiple models

Tags: ember.js

I have one model eg 'reader' and I want to add multiple 'books' model to this object.

reader model defined books field like this:

```
books: DS.hasMany('book', {async: true}),
```

when i create reader I want to add some book models to it. in template, I can list books like this:

```
{{#each books as |book index|}}
    {{book.name}}, {{index}} <br>
{{/each}}

<button {{action 'addReader'}}>add</button><br>
```

how can I pass books to 'addReader' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to pass the parameter to the action then is the same as with a link. So here im iterating over an array of categories with the follow unfollow functionality kind of like twitter:

```
{{action 'unfollow' category}}
```

in your case it would be

```
{{action 'addReader' books}}
```

or `bookss` I think you have a Typo there.

Then on your Controller or Component :

```
addReader:function(books) {
  console.log('Saving books',books);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i fixed typo in my question, it wasnt typo in the code, just here. when i pass books like that to action handler and print the log i get this:  Class {query: Object, store: Class, manager: Class, isLoaded: true, meta: ember$data$lib$system$empty$object$$EmptyObject…}[]: (...)get []: GETTER_FUNCTION()set []: SETTER_FUNCTION(value)__ember1450691277048: "ember399"__ember_meta__: Object__firebaseCleanup: ()__nextSuper: undefinedcontent: (...)get content: GETTER_FUNCTION()set content: SETTER_FUNCTION(value)isLoaded: ...   etc. what can i do with this class? how I get  book there?

Comment: I tried to add my button in {{#each}} loop, and I pass single book object and I can read it ok in action handler, but if I pass all books how can I iterate through them in js code, like {{#each}} is doing in template?

Comment: So your ```books``` will be wrapped in an ember array thats why you see all those getter setter ember_meta when you printed in the console. Take a look at this http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html you can iterate with forEach or use other array method provided that fits your need